# Show that a certain multiplication operator defines a positive operator valued measure (POVM)

Tags: measure-theory, operator-theory

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions on $\mathcal{Q}=\varepsilon\mathbb{Z}$ acting on $\mathcal{H}=L^2(\mathbb{R})$, so that for every $q\in \mathcal{Q}$, $f_n(q)$ is the multiplication operator by
\begin{align}
 f^q_n(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{n[(x-(q-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}))(x-(q+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}))]}} \, .
\end{align}
Is there a way of showing that $f_n$ defines a POVM on $\mathcal{Q}=\varepsilon\mathbb{Z}$ acting on $\mathcal{H}=L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

I have worked with POVMs before, but I am a bit confused on how this is defined with being a sequence of functions and multiplication operator.